# Is android epoch time the same in all devices

Tags: android, epoch

I made an app that syncs data data across devices based on an epoch time. I am currently getting this epoch time by using rest api on a server by using httpurlconnection as follows:

```
public static String getTime(String time){
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try{
        URL url = new URL(SERVERURL);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

        return jsonObject.getString("time");


    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.d("getTime","json object creation failed");
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("getTime", "couldn't get time from server");
    }
    finally {
        try {

            if(urlConnection != null){
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if(bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }

            if(is != null){
                is.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            Log.d("async getGameName","io exception closing buffer");
        }
    }

    return time;
}
```

so that all devices are getting a timestamp from one known source. This method runs in a background service so it does not slows down the app responsiveness, but it is not yielding a good user experience because I need this timestamp to display information to the user and the http request takes long. Some times up to a minute because this depends on the network connectivity, so I wanted to ask if local epoch time is the same across all android devices and if it is what is the best way to get an epoch timestamp on android? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no guaranteed universally correct time for all android devices, since all of their clocks may be different.  Accurate synchronization of time is a fairly difficult problem, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 0):

The epoch time depends on the time synchronization of a device, so two devices might have different values for it.

Also, fetching time information from a REST endpoint does not seem like the most efficient way, as you are also introducing potential delays on the API endpoint in addition to general network latency.

Since Android devices use an NTP server of sorts to get their time, why don't you get time information from the device itself and converting to epoch? The device itself is already getting updated time information so you might just as well use that.

If you want to get the current epoch value from the device itself you can use `[currentTimeMillis()][1]`:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()/1000
```

This returns the number of milliseconds, so to get an epoch value, which is in seconds, just divide by 1000.

Comment: Could you guide me to the api to use to get the timestamp?

Comment: @JeanCarlosHenriquez I have updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I am still suffering in production environment, with ***** devices with totally messed up time. Do not trust the android device time.